# WebTestClient mutateWith apparently not mutating

Tags: csrf, spring-webflux, spring-test, cucumber-jvm

My (Cucumber) BDD unit test using [`WebTestClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.html) is failing (with a 403 Forbidden), when I believe it should be passing. After some debugging, I established that this is because the CSRF check is failing, which suggests the `mutateWith(csrf())` operation is not working. What am I doing wrong?

---

My test scenario:

```
  Scenario Outline: Login
    Given that player "<player>" exists with  password "<password>"
    And presenting a valid CSRF token
    When log in as "<player>" using password "<password>"
    Then program accepts the login
```

My test steps code (note the presence of `client.mutateWith(csrf())`):

```
@SpringBootTest(...)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class WebSteps {

   @Autowired
   private WebTestClient client;

...

   private WebTestClient.ResponseSpec response;

   @Given("presenting a valid CSRF token")
   public void presenting_a_valid_CSRF_token() {
      client.mutateWith(csrf());
   }

   @When("log in as {string} using password {string}")
   public void log_in_as_using_password(final String player,
            final String password) {
      response = client.post().uri("/login")
               .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
               .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("username", player)
                        .with("password", password))
               .exchange();
   }

   @Then("program accepts the login")
   public void program_accepts_the_login() {
      response.expectStatus().isFound().expectHeader().valueEquals("Location",
               "/");
   }

...
```

Comment: I am answering my own question, [as is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite its name, the [`mutateWith()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/reactive/server/WebTestClient.html#mutateWith-org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientConfigurer-) method does not really mutate its object. Rather, it returns a new object that has had the mutation applied. Therefore instead of writing

```
   @Given("presenting a valid CSRF token")
   public void presenting_a_valid_CSRF_token() {
      client.mutateWith(csrf());
   }
```

write

```
   @Given("presenting a valid CSRF token")
   public void presenting_a_valid_CSRF_token() {
      client = client.mutateWith(csrf());
   }
```

This error is more likely to occur in a Cucumber test because of the way that test steps alter shared state (The `client` object), rather than use a fluent API with a long chain of calls.